# Is there a way to resize text in Firefox for Android similar to the Text Resizer addon in Dolphin?

Tags: firefox-for-android

Does anyone know if there is a way to resize text in Firefox for Android similar to the Text Resizer addon in Dolphin?

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Help us help you. You should describe what the Text Resize add-on does and what aspect of the add-on that you want to replicate. Not everyone here had used Dolphin and the add-on or had the time and willingness to install them just to answer your question.

Comment: With that said, did you try "Settings > Display > Text Size"?